# automated docker hub builds won't trigger

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a docker hub repository configured for automated builds. see image below. When I press the "save and trigger build" I get an error page saying nothing more than "Oops, there was an error!".
I tried emailing docker support, but in vain.
Any idea why this is happening and how to resolve?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by Docker support so I'm posting here for anyone who might get into that as well. It appears that Docker was having an issue with bitbucket integration and it is now solved.